# Render Error: TypeError: -- undefined is not an object-- (evaluating 'asset.scales')

Tags: react-native, typeerror

I am new to react-native I have this weird error I tried to solve but unable. I already checked all the same issue posted on GitHub and stack overflow but didn't solve my problem following is my code.
react-native (react-native-cli: 2.0.1)
node (v14.18.2)

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, View  } from 'react-native-web';

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
return (  
    <ImageBackground
        style={styles.background}
        source={require("../assets/background.jpg")}>
        <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo-red.png")} />
        <View style={styles.loginButton}></View>
        <View style={styles.registerButton}></View>
    </ImageBackground>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
background:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
},
loginButton:{
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: '#fc5c65',
},
registerButton:{
    width: "100%",
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: '#4ecdc4  ',
},
logo:{
    width: 100,
    height: 100
},
}); 

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLTVj.png)

Answer (score 1):

It was the file import problem I have to use

```
react-native
```

instead of

```
react-native-web
```

if anyone has the above error use the below import

```
import { Image, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, View, Text} from 'react-native';
```